# Getting syntax error in swagger code

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have following YAML file in which I am getting following error

> YAML Syntax Error Bad indentation of a mapping entry at line 44,
>   column 8: description: get the movies list ^

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /movie:
    # our controller name
    x-swagger-router-controller: movie
    get:
    post:
      description: add a new movie to the list
      # movie info to be stored
      parameters:
        - name: title
          description: Movie properties
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Movie"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GeneralResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
       description: get the movies list
      # define the type of response for Success "200" and Error
        responses:
          "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GetMoviesListResponse"
          default:
            description: Error
            schema:
              $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  GetMoviesListResponse:
    required:
      - movies
    properties:
      # The array of movies
      movies:
        type: array
        items: 
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
            year:
              type: number
            month:
              type: string
  GeneralResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      success:
        type: number
        description: returns 1 if successful
      description:
        type: string
        description: a short comment 
    required:
      - success
      - description
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

Comment: Paste your code into http://editor.swagger.io and follow the hints. It has indentation indicators that can help you align the code.

Comment: This can also be seen in our locally hosted swagger UI. I was able to identify the line on which error occurred, but I was not sure how to resolve it. It is already solved without editor.swagger.io. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
       description: get the movies list
```

should either be aligned with:

```
        default:
```

above it, or with the line

```
      responses:
```

above that. But it is just indented in between those two.